# Text doesn't start from the left top of input text field

Tags: html, css

I have an input field with a fixed height.  The text is vertically centered, but I want it at the top left of the input.

CSS

```
.wideInput{
    text-align: left;
    padding:  0.4em;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<input class="longInput" value="<?php echo $row['foodPrice']; ?>" />
```

Here's a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem > http://jsfiddle.net/9cR5j/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if what that than remove `padding:  0.4em;` and set

```
padding-left:0;
padding-top:0;
padding-bottom:0.4em;
padding-right: 0.4em;
```

After doing change change class name here

```
<input class="wideInput" value="<?php echo $row['foodPrice']; ?>" />
```

instead of `longInput` it will be `wideInput`

---

Update

[**JsFiddle demo with TextArea**](http://jsfiddle.net/9cR5j/2/)

this will work with textarea only because input is just allow to enter value in one line i.e no enter keyallowed or it doent wrap long text , it just add data in one line

Comment: it's not add text from top left corner.

Comment: still at the center horizantally, not at the top

Comment: yes i know, i already changed it, your code doesn't do anything to my page, the same thing still, if you want try it

Comment: the jsFiddle you gave to me is exactly like my code, see it please, the text starts at the center of vertical, not at the top

Comment: Yes, I know. The jsFiddle was for Pranay, not you.

Comment: yes it is on the top left, but now the data is not loaded into the textarea, is textarea is one of the types that can't have a default value? thaaaaaaaaank u for answer, please help me in the data problem,

Comment: i will put this problem as a new question after 15minutes

Answer (score 13):

Instead of `input` why you not try `textarea` ?

```
<textarea class="longInput" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

It will add text from left top corner.

Answer (score 2):

To align left and top you would have to set a smaller height and a padding-bottom:

```
text-align: left;
padding:  0.4em;
padding-bottom:190px;
width: 400px;
height: 10px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your padding is causing the text to begin 0.4em from the left hand side. If you want the text to be truly left-aligned, remove the padding on the left:

```
.wideInput{
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0.4em 0.4em 0.4em 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: it's not add text from top left corner.

Comment: still at the center horizantally, not at the top

Comment: i also said its not working with input if you will change it to textarea it will work.

Comment: That's default behaviour for a `text` input. You can't change that. A `text` input by default can have only a single line. When you increase the height of the element, the browser will force the line to be vertically aligned to the center. If you need to a large input, use `textarea`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `line-height` CSS property on the `input` field to the same as the `height` of that field.

```
height:200px; line-height:200px;
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Pranay Rana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1982525/devang-rathod) said, your padding is causing the problem and his answer is correct. Additionally you can use shortcut propery for `padding`:

```
padding: 0 0.4rem 0.4rem 0;
```

This is the same as:

```
padding-left:0;
padding-top:0;
padding-bottom:0.4em;
padding-right: 0.4em;
```

It takes the values in clockwise order, so first top, right, bottom and then  left. And if you want the text to be on multiple lines, use `textarea` instead of regular `input[type=text]`.