# CSS - How to make the text entered in my input start to be displayed at top-left of the box?

Tags: html, css

I'm working in input with my html css. I would know how to make that, when I enter a text in my box, the text start to be displayed at the top-left of my box ?

Currently it is displayed at the center of my box, here a tiny reproducible example of my work:

```css
/*** messages ***/ 
.messages_flow{ 
    grid-area: messages_flow; 
    width: 85%; 
    height: 85% ;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin: auto;
    display:flex; 
    flex-direction : column; 
    align-items: end; 
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-color: white;  
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding: 15px 10px  ; 
    /* padding-bottom: 15px;  */

}

.message_form { 
    grid-area: message_form;  
    width:  16.76em ;
   
    word-wrap: break-word;   
    /* margin-top: 5em;  */
    display:flex; 
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;  
}

.message_form  input[name="message"] { 
    text-align: end;  
    width:  16.76em ; 
    height: 4em;
    justify-self: start;
    margin-right: 1em;
    margin-top: 0.5em; 
} 
form, input { 
    border-radius: 10px; 
}
```

```html
  <form
  class="message_form"
  onSubmit={this.send}
  >
    <input  
    name="message" 
    type="text"  />
    <input id="send" type="submit"                   value="Send" />
</form>
```

Any hint would be great,
Thanks

Comment: Try removing the `text-align: end` inside your `.message_form  input[name="message"]` style

Comment: Also, I've found an identical topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382422/text-doesnt-start-from-the-left-top-of-input-text-field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just erase the `text-align: end;` from your inputs CSS.

For *top* (and left) alignment you would need to use a `textarea` element, not a regular text input.

```css
/*** messages ***/ 
.messages_flow{ 
    grid-area: messages_flow; 
    width: 85%; 
    height: 85% ;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin: auto;
    display:flex; 
    flex-direction : column; 
    align-items: end; 
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-color: white;  
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding: 15px 10px  ; 
    /* padding-bottom: 15px;  */

}

.message_form { 
    grid-area: message_form;  
    width:  16.76em ;
   
    word-wrap: break-word;   
    /* margin-top: 5em;  */
    display:flex; 
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;  
}

.message_form  input[name="message"] { 
    width:  16.76em ; 
    height: 4em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    margin-top: 0.5em; 
} 
form, input { 
    border-radius: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<form
  class="message_form"
  onSubmit={this.send}
  >
    <input  
    name="message" 
    type="text"  />
    <input id="send" type="submit"                   value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: Well put. I pretty much said the same thing but you got in before I finished. :) +1

Answer (score 2):

If you need multiple lines, you could use a textarea element instead. Then the cursor would start at the top left.

```
<textarea name="message" />
```

If you only need left alignment, then removing the `text-align: center` line would do the trick.

Another option, if you want to have an input element with only one line is, instead of using height to make the text element taller, you can add padding to the top and bottom of the element but add more to the bottom. For example:

```css
#message {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input id="message" type='text' name='message'>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best you can do is add `text-align: left;` (or remove your text-align in your input CSS as Johannes suggested) to your input but I can't think of a way to vertically align an input's contents to the top using my knowledge of CSS. However, you can style a `<textarea></textarea>` much easily to meet your requirement. Hope this helps.

```css
/*** messages ***/ 
.messages_flow{ 
    grid-area: messages_flow; 
    width: 85%; 
    height: 85% ;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin: auto;
    display:flex; 
    flex-direction : column; 
    align-items: end; 
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-color: white;  
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding: 15px 10px  ; 
    /* padding-bottom: 15px;  */

}

.message_form { 
    grid-area: message_form;  
    width:  16.76em ;
   
    word-wrap: break-word;   
    /* margin-top: 5em;  */
    display:flex; 
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;  
}

.message_form  textarea[name="message"] { 
    width:  16.76em ; 
    height: 4em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    resize: none;
}

form, input, textarea { 
    border-radius: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<form class="message_form" onSubmit={this.send}>
    <textarea name="message" rows="1"></textarea>
    <input id="send" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```